# TestNG: How to Ignore the method in dependsOnMethods if it was skipped and continue execution

Tags: selenium, testng

I have a TestNG class with the following methods.

```
@Test(priority=4)
public void Test1() 
{   
}

@Test(priority=5, dependsOnMethods={"Test1"})
public void Test2() 
{
    throw new SkipException("SKIP");
}

@Test(priority=6, dependsOnMethods={"Test1"})
public void Test3() 
{
}

@Test(priority=7, dependsOnMethods={"Test1"})
public void Test4() 
{
}

@Test(priority=8, dependsOnMethods={"Test2","Test3","Test4"})
public void Test5() 
{
}
```

What I would like to achieve is:
Test2, Test3 and Test 4 depends on Test1. So Only if Test1 pass then I need to continue.

And Test5 depends on Test2, Test3 and Test4.
But I can skip any test (i.e Test2, Test3 or Test4) and still want to continue my execution of Test5 if other Test's did not fail.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: IMO, the logic you are looking for is invalid. `Test2`, `Test3` and `Test4` all are dependsOnMethods on `Test1`. So incase `Test1` passes, all of them will get executed as per `priority`. But `Test5` will get executed only when all the `"Test2"`,`"Test3"`,`"Test4"` are `Passed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alwaysRun=true

```
@Test(alwaysRun = true, priority=8, dependsOnMethods={"Test2","Test3","Test4"})
    public void Test5() 
    {
    }
```

Test5 will be executed if any of the dependent test is skipped and **also it will be executed if any one of dependent test fails.**